# How do I debug the htaccess processes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, logging, trace

My magento store has this in the htaccess:

```
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
```

I would like to log what is going on in my htaccess process. I have tried adding this code:

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 2
```

But I'm getting an "Internal Server Error" or a Not Found erro when run it with the RewriteLog lines.

Any tips / help?

Thanks!

Comment: You can’t use `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` in .htaccess files.

Comment: Set log file from httpd.conf, you can activate debbuging in your store to know what is doing magento behind. Check this http://www.redlightblinking.com/blog/magento-tutorials/magento-debugging-how-to-debug-template-paths-logging-and-display-errors

Comment: Gumbo: What can I do then? I am in a GoDaddy Linux server and I don't think I have access to the httpd.conf. MMU: The store debugging is useful, but not in this case as the problem is on the server side (before Magento).

Comment: Try http://blog.tolleiv.de/2010/01/debugging-mod_rewrite/ or http://www.latenightpc.com/blog/archives/2007/09/05/a-couple-ways-to-debug-mod_rewrite

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before you can't turn on the rewrite log from inside htaccess files, and since you're in GoDaddy's walled garden, there's not much you can do.

> Any tips / help?

Create an offline test server:

1. Find a linux machine or install one in virtualbox on your windows machine.
2. Install apache
3. Install php or whatever other modules magento needs
4. Move your entire website to your `/var/www/localhost/htdocs` directory (or whereever the document root is)
5. In apache's config, turn on rewrite log
6. go to `http://localhost/your-site` and see what the log says.

Comment: exactly, and don't fall for "the easy way" using some tricks to see a variable. I just wasted a lot of time that way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules/#41908462